# error in /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm on debian

Tags: html, perl, calendar.app, parsing

how to fix this? when i type `perl /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm` i get

> syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 64, near "$t qw(week month year)"
>   Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 65.
>   Global symbol "$date" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 65.
>   Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 65.
>   Global symbol "%args" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 67.
>   Global symbol "$date" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 67.
>   Global symbol "%args" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 68.
>   Global symbol "$url" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 68.
>   Global symbol "%args" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 69.
>   syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm line 70, near "}"
>   /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm has too many errors.

Comment: meanwhile i fixed it. in the mentioned line 64 the were parentheses missing: `foreach my $t qw(week month year) {` instead of `foreach my $t (qw(week month year)) {`. with this modification there is no output at all when typing `perl /usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm`. Also `/usr/share/doc/libical-parser-html-perl/examples/ical2html -h` puts out the usage. I got an error before.

Answer (score 1):

there was imho a syntax error in `/usr/share/perl5/iCal/Parser/HTML.pm`. the following line

> foreach my $t qw(week month year) {

has to look like this

> foreach my $t (qw(week month year)) {

now everything works fine.

Comment: You are right. Even the "latest" version have this issue (4 years old) - this module seems to not have been tested properly.